# Why does IDEA open large file faster than NOTEPAD++?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, notepad++, system

My friend got this as an interview question. I'm curious about the answer.

My thought is

1. IDEA is allowed to use more memory than NOTEPAD++
2. IDEA will show the first hundreds of lines first, while load the remaining in the background. NotePad++ won't show anything until it read the whole file.

Am I correct? Any comments are welcome. Thanks

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has special mode for large files. Check the sources if you want to understand how it works: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/largeFilesEditor.

Answer (score -2):

Well the difference is behind **memory management** so Intellij (on starting) reserve enough memory heap  to deal with future complicated tasks(for programming: editing code, compiling, ...) that's why the task of *opening large files* is easier than in notpad who is created to do simple task *editing small texts* quickly.